# Make payment to different bank accounts through razorpay payment gateway integration in node.js

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, razorpay

Suppose I am a middle man like amazon e-commerce.
I have bank details of many retailers.

But I want my customers to pay directly to retailers.(Not paying to me in between)

How can I achieve this?

I have already checked razorpay routes. But there is no api to add bank accounts in razorpay.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Add Bank Accounts information of each retailer using Razorpay Dashboard.
Under Route Menu option -> Accounts -> Add Accounts.
Note: Every account added here must be activated with KYC.
Once you add accounts, you will get unique 'Account_ID' for every account you have added. You can use them to transfer/split/route payments.
[Refer image given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM5Ue.jpg)